# Is it possible to use 'INSERT INTO SELECT' with dynamic query stored in variable?

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamicquery

please advise or give a hint:

secenario:

- language: PL/SQL ORACLE
- part of procedure
- perform "INSERT INTO ( SELECT ... )'
- SELECT query is in variable with additional bindings in WHERE clause
- the code is part of procedure

Origial working code with cursor:

```
 OPEN ret_cursor FOR v_query using v_1, v_2, v_3;

LOOP
    FETCH ret_cursor  INTO   v_text1, v_number1;
    EXIT WHEN ret_cursor %NOTFOUND;
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name' || v_text1  );
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value' || to_char( round ( v_number1, 2 ), 'FM99990.00') );
END LOOP;
```

Now I would like to achieve the same but insert the data to table in kind of this

```
INSERT INTO TBL_NAME
(
    text1, val1
)
v_query using using v_1, v_2, v_3;
```

v_query: holds select query with biding in where clause to v_1, v_2, v_3

my problem is how to exexute the binding + query that the command INSERT INTO works .....

Thank You very much for help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the whole insert dynamic, by concatenating your variable onto your fixed `insert into ...` part, and running the combined string; something like:

```
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO TBL_NAME (text1, val1) ' || v_query
  using v_1, v_2, v_3;
```

Of course, you can put the fixed part and/or the combined string into their own variables, which might make it clearer and make debugging easier.